# discord.py error when we pass named arguments

Tags: discord.py

I am getting error if I don't pass one of the optional parameters in discord extension command.
Code is as below:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg1:int=1, arg2:int=2):
  await ctx.send('You passed {} and {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
```

The code works for following cases

```
$test 3 5
$test 3
$test
```

But, it won't work for

```
$test arg1=1 arg2=2
$test arg1=1
$test arg2=2
```

In the logs, I can see errors such as this:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "arg1".`

Appreciate any suggestons. I can read variable arguments and then get parameters. But, looking for shortcut if there is any.

Comment: You are asking for the arguments to be passed in int only `arg1: int = 1`, and you're passing a string. What did you expect was going to happen?

Comment: How do you pass optional variables in random order? Python syntax is generally arg=value. I was expecting similar thing here too. Anyway, I am more interested in knowing if there is any simpler way to pass named optional arguments in non ordered way.

Comment: You can't do that. If you want to, you'll have to accept it as a string and then manipulate it. If you change it to `arg1 = 1` in the function, then passing `$test arg1=1` will give `arg1 = 'arg1=1'`.

Comment: I was something like this. https://github.com/lukeciel/discord-argparse Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library made it possible:

https://github.com/lukeciel/discord-argparse

Using this, we can send variable args as key value pair and convert into the format you require.